# Reordering proof of $p$-adic logarithm fundamental property

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, p-adic-number-theory

I am reading a book on $p$-adic analysis and am currently stuck at the proof of the following theorem:

> **Theorem** The $p$-adic logarithm satisfies the fundamental property $$\ln_p(xy) = \ln_p(x) + \ln_p(y)$$

As a reminder: the $p$-adic logarithm is defined as $$\ln_p(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty (-1)^{n + 1} \frac{(x-1)^n}n$$

The proof they give is the following:

> The following identity $$\log(1 + X) + \log(1 + Y) - \log(1 + X + Y + XY) = 0$$ holds for formal power series. One can check directly (by expanding and reordering terms) that all coefficients of the resulting series reduce to zero.

Where $\log(1 + X)$ is defined as $$\log(1 + X) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty (-1)^{n + 1} \frac{X^n}n$$

I understand that you must be able to rearrange the above equation/series to get zero, as the identity can be proven through other ways. However, I'm a bit confused as to what specific reordering they are referring to here. I've tried developing the partial sums till $n = 4$ but wasn't able to find anything interesting.

Comment: Maybe this is just an easy corollary of the replacement principle

Comment: @FShrike what is the "replacement principle"?

Comment: Here is a cautionary tale about turning formal convergence into numerical converges. The formal power series $g(x) = \exp(2x - 2x^2) = 1 + 2x - (8/3)x^2 - (4/3)x^2 + (8/5)x^5 + \cdots$ turns out to have coefficients in $\mathbf Z_2$ that tend to $0$, so $g(x)$ converges at all $x$ in $\mathbf Z_2$, but while intuitively you might think $g(1) = \exp(2-2) = \exp(0) = 1$, that's not true. It turns out that $g(x) \equiv 1 + 2x \bmod 4\mathbf Z_2$ for all $x \in \mathbf Z_2$, so $g(1) \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ and thus $g(1)$ is definitely not $1$. In fact,  $g(1) = -1$.

Comment: @KCd I messed up; it’s actually called the “permanence principle”. Something like, the coefficients of that combined series are all zero by the usual proofs in $\Bbb R$ so the series *is* zero in $\Bbb Z_p$ whenever it converges. Although I’ve been told this is rigorous by others on this site I wouldn’t know where it goes wrong in your cautionary tale

Comment: I take that back slightly; the situation of your cautionary tale is different to the one I described. I think $\ln x+\ln y-\ln(xy)$ is rigorously zero in any setting in which the series makes sense and converges since its coefficients are provably identically zero

Comment: Perhaps I should say [… makes sense and *absolutely* converges] so that we can reorder the terms suitably

Comment: @FShrike when a $p$-adic infinite series converges, an arbitrary rearrangement also converges to the same value.  So there is no need to use a concept like absolute convergence, which in the case of real or complex infinite series is equivalent to the numerical value being unaffected by rearrangements of terms.

Comment: @FShrike the definition of evaluating a formal power series is that you substitute a number for $x$ only when the series is in standard form as $\sum_{n \geq 0} a_nx^n$.  So if you start with a series written in some other way, like a composition $f(g(x))$ of formal power series where $g(x)$ has constant term $0$ (so the formal composition makes sense) and you have a number $a$ such that this composition *in standard form* converges at $a$, $g(a)$ converges, and $f(x)$ converges at $g(a)$, then you want a proof that the value of $f(g(x))$ in standard form at $a$ equals $f(g(a))$.

Comment: My example shows that the idea in the previous comment need not always work: use $f(x) = \exp(x)$, $g(x) = 2x - 2x^2$, and $a = 1$ in $\mathbf Q_2$.

Comment: @KCd Ah so you’re saying, we would need to check that we can prove the series for $\ln x+\ln y-\ln xy$ can be reordered into a standard bivariate power series (with the same coefficients as those in $\Bbb R$) and we need to make this proof *in $Z_p$* and only then we can use the permanence principle (being, those coefficients are all zero by an easier real analytic proof, hence the series is one with zero coefficients in $Z_p$ hence its evaluation is always zero)

Comment: @FShrike  I am not suggesting at all to use the "permanence principle" and I don't claim to know what the ordering of terms in a standard *bivariate* series even means. The idea is worthwhile for intuition but not for other purposes. Use it with caution. In the old days people claimed "what is true at each step is true in the limit", which viewed too broadly is clearly incorrect (try the property "being a rational number").

Answer (score 4):

I agree that kind of "formal to numerical" reasoning is dubious. What book are you reading that in?

A different proof, based on differentiation and recentering of $p$-adic power series, is Theorem 8.5 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/infseriespadic.pdf).

Comment: It's Theorem 3.23. on pages 89/90 in _$p$-adic Analysis Compared with Real by Svetlana Katok_

Comment: @JonasHardt  the treatment of infinite series in Gouvea's book on $p$-adic numbers is probably going to be more to your liking.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree that the “formal to numerical” reasoning is dubious. But it *is* tricky to pin down precisely what happens.

The simple story is the following: the formal power series $S(x,y)=\log(1+x)+\log(1+y)-\log(1+x+y+xy)$ is such that, when $z,w \in \mathbb{C}$ have small enough absolute value, $S(z,w)=0$ (by the property of the logarithm). By the theory of holomorphic functions, this means that the power series $S$ itself is zero. But when $z,w \in \mathfrak{m}_{\mathbb{C}_p}$, $S(z,w)$ (which is zero since $S=0$) is equal to $\ln_p(1+z)+\ln_p(1+w)-\ln_p(1+z+w+zw)$. QED.

Now, how to formalize that? The issue is that it’s not clear that the formal series $\log(1+P(x,y))$ (where $P$ is a polynomial with $P(0,0)=0$) evaluates at $(z,w)$ (when defined) to $\log_{an}(1+P(z,w))$ (where $\log_{an}$ is an “analytic logarithm”, ie an actual function instead of a power series).

To prove it, we need to introduce a bit of notation.

Let $K$ be a field with a nontrivial absolute value $|\cdot|$ and completion $\overline{K}$.

Call a power series $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) =\sum_{\alpha \in \mathbb{N}^n}{a_{\alpha}x^{\alpha}} \in K[[x_1,\ldots,x_n]]$ *tame* if there exists $r_1,\ldots,r_n >0$ such that $|a_{\alpha}| = O(r_1^{-\alpha_1} \ldots r_n^{-\alpha_n})$.

We can then consider the function $E(f): (z_1,\ldots,z_n) \in D(f):=\cup_r{B(0,r_1) \times B(0,r_n)} \longmapsto f(z_1,\ldots,z_n)$, where the balls are open balls in $\overline{K}$, and we take the reunion over all $r$ as above.

It’s not hard to see that if $f,g$ are tame, then $f+g$ (resp. $fg$) is tame, $D(f+g) \supset D(f) \cap D(g)$ (resp. $D(fg) \supset D(f) \cap D(g)$), and the functions $E(f+g)$ and $E(f)+E(g)$ (resp. $E(fg)$ and $E(f)E(g)$) are (well defined and) equal on $D(f) \cap D(g)$.

The key lemma is the following one.

*Lemma*: let $f \in K[[T]]$ be tame. Let $P(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ be a polynomial with entries in $K$ and $P(0)=0$. Then

1. $f \circ P$ is tame.
2. The functions $E(f \circ P)$ and $E(f) \circ P$ coincide on $D(0,r_1) \times \ldots \times D(0,r_n)$ for some $r_1, \ldots, r_n >0$.
3. if moreover $K$ is non-Archimedean and the coefficients of $P$ are in $O_K$, then $D(f \circ P) \supset [D(f)\cap D(0,1)]^n$ and the functions $E(f \circ P)$ and $E(f) \circ P$ coincide on $[D(f) \cap D(0,1)]^n$.

[Remark: when we apply it, $n=2$, $K$ is $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{C}_p$, and $f(T)=\log(1+T)$, $P(x,y) \in \{x,y,x+y+xy\}$.]

*Proof*: I only prove 1) and 2), the proof of 3) is similar but we can replace most of the sums with sups, which makes everything easier (the binomial coefficients lie in the unit ball, $M=1$ and we can drop $r$ from all the estimates).

Let $r >0$ be the number of nonzero coefficients of $P$ and $M \geq 1$ be at least the maximum of their absolute values.

So we can write $P(X)=\sum_{i=1}^r{p_{i}X^{\beta_i}}$.

Write $f=\sum_{n \geq 0}{a_nT^n}$, and let $1 \geq s>0$ be such that $|a_n| = O(s^{-n})$.

If $|z_1|, \ldots, |z_n| < s/Mr$, then $|P(z)| < s$ and thus $E(f) \circ P$ is defined at $z$.

Now, $f \circ P = \sum_{k \geq 0}{a_kP^k}=\sum_{k \geq 0}{\sum_{k=m_1+\ldots+m_r}{a_k\binom{k}{m_1,\ldots,m_r}p_1^{m_1} \ldots p_r^{m_r}X^{m_1\beta_1+\ldots m_r\beta_r}}}.$

In this sum, in any term of degree $k$, the coefficient has absolute value at most $Ck^r(rM/s)^k$ (where $|a_k| \leq Cs^{-k}$).
Moreover, in this infinite sum, there are only at most $(|\alpha|+1)^{r}$ instances of a term of given (multi-degree) $\alpha$.

In particular, in the formal series $f \circ P$, a coefficient of degree $k$ has absolute value at most $C(k+1)^{2r}(rM/s)^k$, hence $f \circ P$ is tame and $D(f \circ P) \supset D(0,s/rM)^n$.

Let $(f \circ P)_k$ be the truncation of the formal series $(f \circ P)$ to its terms of degree $\leq k$.

Then by definition, $E(f \circ P)(z_1,\ldots,z_n)$ is the limit of the $(f\circ P)_k(z_1,\ldots,z_n)$.

Now, since $\sum_{d>k}{a_dP^d}$ contains no term of degree $\leq k$, it follows that $(f \circ P)_k-\sum_{d=0}^k{a_kP^k}$ is sum of a subset of the $a_d\binom{d}{m_1,\ldots,m_r}p_1^{m_1} \ldots p_r^{m_r}X^{m_1 \beta_1+\ldots m_r\beta_r}$ where $d > k$ and $m_1+\ldots+m_r=d$.

In particular, if $|z_i| \leq \sigma/Mr \leq 1$ with $\sigma < s$, then \begin{align*}|(f \circ P)_k(z_1,\ldots,z_n)-\sum_{d=0}^k{a_dP^d(z_1,\ldots,z_n)}|& \leq \sum_{d > k}{Cs^{-d}\sum_{d=m_1+\ldots+m_r}{\binom{d}{m_1,\ldots,m_r} M^{m_1\beta_1+\ldots+m_r\beta_r}(\sigma/Mr)^{m_1\beta_1+\ldots+m_r\beta_r}}}\\
& \leq C\sum_{m_1+\ldots m_r > k}{\binom{m_1+\ldots+m_r}{m_1,\ldots,m_r}(\sigma/s)^{m_1|\beta_1|+\ldots+m_r|\beta_r|}}\\
& \leq C\sum_{d > k}{d^r(\sigma/s)^d}.
\end{align*}

When $k \rightarrow \infty$, we find $E(f \circ P)(z_1,\ldots,z_n)=(E(f) \circ P) (z_1,\ldots,z_n)$.

This proves 1) and 2).

Comment: Typo: Let $f \in K[[T]]$ be tame. (Not $fS$.) --- To reconcile this with @KCd's example from a comment ($f = exp(T), P(X) = 2x-2x^2$): I would think the power series for exp *is* "tame", but the crucial part in your assertion 2 is that the formal evaluation is guaranteed to match the evaluation only on a possibly smaller disk than the one where the formal evaluation converges (in this example, certainly something that is smaller than the one of radius $1$ where $f\circ P$ "accidentally" converges).

Comment: When you define $E(f)$ you left out $\cdots \times$ between $B(0,r_1)$ and $B(0,r_n)$.  In the 2nd part of the lemma, change $\times \cdot \times$ to $\times \cdots \times$.

Comment: When I said in my answer that formal to numerical behavior of power series composition is dubious, I did not mean it can't be made precise, but only that it is a subtle point that one should be suspicious about because formal convergence is a very different thing from numerical convergence. In the 2nd edition of Gouvea's book on $p$-adic numbers he states and proves a sufficient condition for composition of formal power series in one indeterminate to behave well with respect to numerical evaluation. Many other books on $p$-adic analysis explain this point less carefully.

Comment: Btw, since your statement only says "for some $r_1, ... r_n$", this falls short of proving OP's assertion which presumably reads the log identity holds for all $x,y$ for which it makes sense. I.e. we would still need to show that in the case at hand, one can take $r=1$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg: isn’t that covered by 3) in my lemma? Thanks for pointing out the typo!